# Develop Wordpress plugin settings page procedural or OOP?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

Is it a problem develop wordpress settings page in html?
When i search the internet and github, i found (almost) tutorials how build a settings page in OOP.

I have a book 'Wordpress Plugin Development' [https://www.amazon.com/Professional-WordPress-Plugin-Development-Williams/dp/0470916222](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470916222)  but is a bit outdated (print in 2011) and i don't know if some functions are depricated.

I have also the book 'Pro Wordpress Design and Development', print in 2015.
In the last book they build a settings page NOT in OOP, but build in html.

Is it a problem building a settings-page with html and not in OOP?
Is this future-proof?

Comment: Build it however you want, as long as it's clean and works.  Turn on debugging and if you're using any deprecated functions, WordPress will tell you.  It all outputs html in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I developing in the past some very small plugins and try follow a way they the code is clean, structural and with a lot of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing a Plugin, most places I have read recomend to go OOP, if you are developing a theme or for a theme, the recomendation is to go with pluiggable functions. This is functios wrapped in an if that determines if the function has already been defined, anybody can later on override you function, normally in the functions.php script.

Now for plugins there are some skeletons or boilerplate that using oop separate admin functions from public functions, and also separate logic from presentation. And also put hooks all in the same place. You can search a bit on this a find one you feel confortable with.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this useful info.

Answer (score 1):

In the body of your question, you are talking about two different things... html is a client side language where as OOP stands for `O`bject-`O`riented `P`rogramming --- which is a programming paradigm and has it's applications in languages such as Java, Python, Ruby, etc.

PHP on the other hand, allows one to program either `procedurally` or `OOP`

So the question is not which to pick... it's whatever style you are comfortable with (I recommend going the OOP route).

Lastly, which ever you pick, you will be writing HTML for things like radio buttons, input boxes, etc. on the settings view. And speaking of views, if you go the MVC route (which stands for `M`odel-`V`iew-`C`ontroller---which is an architectural pattern---your HTML will be inside the `View`

Comment: In my question i tried explain in my best english. I'm more comfortable with procedural php.

Answer (score 1):

It will be best , if you will go to build WP plugin through OOPS . Because you don’t really have to worry about clashing with functions defined elsewhere .

Comment: Okay, so if follow the advice is better learn OOP before developing plugins.